# "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast" when assigning chars to arrays individually

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, for-loop

I'm having some trouble knowing the difference between assigning chars to this array. I globally declared

```
char charlist[7];
```

and then proceded to make a function

```
int stringthing()
{
    for(int i=0; i < 7; i++)
    {
        charlist[i] = 'G';
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then declare it in main. It works fine when I assign values with the for loop, but when I use

```
int stringthing()
{
    charlist[0] = "M";
    charlist[1] = "T";
    charlist[2] = "W";
    charlist[3] = "R";
    charlist[4] = "F";
    charlist[5] = "S";
    charlist[6] = "U";
    return 0;
}
```

and declare this in main, I get the error "assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]". It's this the same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing the quotes in your second example from double-quotes to single-quotes. Right now you're trying to set each array element to a string rather than a character.